# SetCursorPos(int x, int y) use float variables

Tags: c#

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648394(v=vs.85).aspx

Can I use this function using float variables? Is there another function using which I can use float variables instead of int?

thanks

Comment: You can just cast the float to an int first and then P/Invoke. The rounding wouldn't really matter much.

Comment: the net library has both a Point object and a PointF object (float).  Make sure you are using the correct object.

Comment: rounding matters for my project. In game for close objects it doesnt matter but for long range it does. Isn't there another method to do this trick?

Comment: If you store the co-ordinates to calculate with separately and derive the co-ordinates for display from them then you should not have so much trouble with accuracy.

Comment: what you meanderieve it for display? if i store coordinates why will it matter? if still i will have to round it than it wont change anything. sorry if i misunderstood something.

Comment: _"rounding matters for my project"_ -- the `SetCursorPos()` function doesn't care. No matter how important rounding is for your project, it still can only position the cursor on _integer_ pixel coordinates. The cursor itself cannot be located any more precisely than that. Please explain what problem you are _really_ trying to solve. Provide a good [mcve] that clearly illustrates the problem, with a detailed explanation of what that code does and what you want it to do instead.

Comment: I just wanted to know if there is any alternatives to this function. So there isn't... I just asked if there is or you know some tricks to do this. So there is no solution to this. I will just have to find other solution without moving cursor.

Comment: Perhaps if you regard the volume behind the cursor as a cone instead of a line it will help.